# Emacs / AUCTeX slow to start

Tags: emacs, latex, auctex

When I run `emacs test.ltx`, it takes about 5 seconds for the buffer to open.  The problem exists even when my init file and `test.ltx` are empty.  `M-x emacs-init-time` returns 0.1 seconds. `*Messages*` says `Applying style hooks... done`. There is no delay when instead I run `emacs -Q test.ltx`, or when I open non-TeX files.

Comment: If you have a blank empty file named `test.ltx`, does it still take 5 seconds?  If not, have you tried bisecting your `test.ltx` to find out what sections of code inside `test.ltx` are causing the delay?  If you isolate your problem and still can't resolve it, then post the code within `test.ltx` that is causing your 5 second delay so other forum participants can duplicate your issue and help you decide whether it's something you can fix or whether a bug report to the AUCTeX team is the best way to handle it.

Comment: It takes 5 seconds even with an empty `test.ltx`.